# Laravel Carbon Data Missing

Tags: php, laravel, format, php-carbon

In my model I have the following:

```
protected $dates = [
    'start',
    'end',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];
```

I am using a datetime picker to insert the start and end dates, in this format:

```
2016-01-23 22:00
```

Without the seconds. When I do it like this, I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Data missing
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-01-23 22:00') in Model.php line 3015
```

If I do include the seconds, it works. The seconds are not important to me, and I do not want to include them in my datetime picker fields. Any way around this so I can still use those fields as date fields?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

## tl;dr

Your date string and your date format is different, you have to change the format string or modify the date string so they match.

## Explanation

### The Problem

This error arises when Carbon's `createFromFormat` function receieves a date string that doesn't match the passed format string. More precisely this comes from the [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function, because Carbon just calls that:

```php
public static function createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz = null)
{
    if ($tz !== null) {
        $dt = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time, static::safeCreateDateTimeZone($tz));
    } else {
        $dt = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time); // Where the error happens.
    }

    if ($dt instanceof DateTime) {
        return static::instance($dt);
    }

    $errors = static::getLastErrors();
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(implode(PHP_EOL, $errors['errors'])); // Where the exception was thrown.
}
```

#### Not enough data

If your date string is "shorter" than the format string like in this case:

```php
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-01-04 00:52');
```

Carbon will throw:

> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
>   Data missing

#### Too much data

If your date string is "longer" than the format string like in this case:

```php
 Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', '2017-01-02 00:27:00');
```

Carbon will throw:

> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
>   Trailing data

### Under the hood

According to the [documentation on mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators) the default date format is: `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`. The date processing happens in the [Model's `asDateTime` function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3053). In the last condition the [`getDateFormat` function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3118) is called, thats where the custom format comes from. The default format is [defined in the Database's `Grammar` class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php#L161).

### Solution

You have to make sure that the date string matches the format string.

#### Change the format string

You can override the default format string like this:

```php
class Event extends Model {
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i';
}
```

There is two problem with this approach:

- This will apply to every field defined in the model's `$dates` array.
- You have to store the data in this format in the database.

#### Edit and format the date strings

My recommended solution is that the date format should stay the default `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` and you should complete the missing parts of the date, like this:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $requestData['start_time'] .= ':00';
    $requestData['end_time'] .= ':00';
    $event = new Event($requestData);
    $event->save();
}
```

And when you want to use the date you should format it:

```php
public function show(Request request, $eventId) {
    $event = Event::findOrFail($eventId);
    $startTime = $event->start_time->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    $endTime = $event->end_time->format('Y-m-d H:i');
}
```

Of course the fields should be mutated to dates:

```php
class Event extends Model {
    protected $dates = [
        'start_time',
        'end_time',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Such a quality answer. I couldn't help but comment this unproductive comment. :)

Comment: I have the same problem this solution hasnt helped me,can you please take a look

Comment: This is great for datetimes, but a PITA for date-only fields. It doesn't make sense to add a time to those & they also can't be stored that way; however there's a big ambiguity in naming, as they are "dates" in the truest sense

Comment: When I am using Postgresql, some time values are saved without millisecond part (when it is just zero). Then the date format will always be making error like above. So at last I can only fix it with specific accessor for the field. But this solution just ignored the original data format.

Comment: The answer is perfect, but IMO, according to Laravel's documentation, this shouldn't be required:
_When a column is considered a date, you may set its value to a UNIX timestamp, date string (Y-m-d), date-time string, or a DateTime / Carbon instance. The date's value will be correctly converted and stored in your database_
See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators). The reality is that it doesn't work according to the docs, and we must resort to hacks like this.

Answer (score 6):

## Models

This function disabled, the emulations for carbon in Datetimes
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#date-mutators

```
public function getDates()
{
    return [];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the $dateFormat in your model as Christian says, but if you don't want to imply the updated_at and created_at fields into the operation you can use events to "correct" the datetime object before saving it into the database.

Here you have the official doc about it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events

Comment: Accepting this as it gives me more options, totally missed the `$dateFormat` option.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set  `protected $dateFormat` to `'Y-m-d H:i`' in your model, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not omitting the "created_at" or "updated_at" fields in some rows in your database, which are required; if that is the case delete the records where they have those empty fields or enter a value in the valid timestamp format, example '2018-09-01 15:18:53'.

Answer (score 0):

**This is one possibility**

You need to check the column of resultant data. If your column name 'created_at' or 'updated_at' is null, then it will through this error.

**How to Solve ?**
First of all, you need to store the data in those two columns using Laravel carbon.
Eg:

```
$user = new User();
$user->created_at = Carbon::now()->setTime(0,0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$user->updated_at = Carbon::now()->setTime(0,0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$user->save();
```

That's All, I hope it will work

Happy Coding....

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was with SQLServerGrammar located into the vendor (vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar.php).
Default in SQLServerGramma is `Y-m-d H:i:s.v`.

We extended the class end removed `.v`.