# Laravel, Carbon, and Validations

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4, php-carbon

I'm running into an odd validation problem in Laravel 4 & Carbon.

I have a form that has some required general fields at the top (a couple of drop-downs and a text field), then a series of date & time fields that are not required.

I have a validator set up to have the first 3 fields required, and the date/time fields set to 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i' (seconds are not important here).

The "airline_open", "airline_close", "hotel_open", "hotel_close" fields below are the ones causing the problems.

As long as the required fields are filled in, everything works great. If the required fields are not filled in, and there are no date/time fields filled in, also great (I get appropriate messaging). However, if any of the required fields are not filled in, and any of the date/time fields are filled in with the expected format (no seconds), I get an exception thrown by Carbon. (Interestingly, if I include the seconds for the time, it doesn't thrown the exception, but gives the validation error.)

This exception seems to be similar to this problem: [Laravel Carbon Data Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968061/laravel-carbon-data-missing)

However, given that everything works as designed as long as the required fields are filled in, it feels like I should be able to make this work without having to mess around with Carbon's date format.

Any ideas?

Adding some code:

Validator:

```
        'direction' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'notes' => 'required',
        'callback_time' => 'date_format:H:i',
        'callback_time2' => 'required_if:callback_type, 4|date_format:H:i',
        'airline_open' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i',
        'airline_close' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i',
        'hotel_open' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i',
        'hotel_close' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i'
    );
```

From the form (the airline_open & airline_close fields). The "now" button calls some js to populate the field with the date & time in the desired format:

```
        <tr class="airline-reservation @if ($data->airline_reservation == 0) _hide @endif">
            <td width="25%">{{ trans('nationalbank.call.form.open') }}:</td>
            <td width="25%">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="airline_open" id="airline_open" @if ($data->airline_open > 0)) value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$data->airline_open)->format('Y-m-d H:i') }}" @endif size="30">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info btn-xs nowbtn" id="now-airline_open">now</a>
            </td>
            <td width="25%">{{ trans('nationalbank.call.form.close') }}:</td>
            <td width="25%">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="airline_close" id="airline_close" @if ($data->airline_close > 0)) value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$data->airline_close)->format('Y-m-d H:i') }}" @endif size="30">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info btn-xs nowbtn" id="now-airline_close">now</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

[Screenshot of error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq8AD.png)

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: Additionally, if I change the field validation & formatting to include the seconds, but remove the seconds from the time in the field, I still get the exception thrown. If I enter garbage (non-date/time text), I get the validation error as expected, but an "incomplete" date/time (e.g. removing the time and just leaving a date) throws the exception.

Comment: Please post the exact error you're getting. The error may be to do with saving of the date rather than validating it.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the error above. The message is "Data missing (View: /var/www/novus-calltracker-2/app/modules/nationalbank/views/call/form.blade.php) "

Answer (score 0):

The validation is failing because you can't save such date in DB you need to parse it.

I recommend first putting the date fields in your model under $dates variable

```
protected $dates = ['your_date'];
```

and then make a setter and getter:

```
// save the date in UTC format in DB table
public function setYourDateAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['your_date'] = Carbon::parse($date);
}

// convert the UTC format to my format
public function getYourDateAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['your_date'])->format('d.m.Y H:i');
}
```

Comment: But if I have the required fields populated, it does save in my database fine (with the seconds always set to 00). See the code above that I added while typing this for how I'm handling the display of the date.

Comment: Issue isn't related to validation. I've posted a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the code in your view `form.blade.php`.

Where you are calling the following:

```
Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$data->airline_open)->format('Y-m-d H:i')
```

Change this to:

```
(new Carbon\Carbon($data->airline_open))->format('Y-m-d H:i')
```

Do this for both the lines where you use Carbon, and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to do it!