# Data missing error in laravel while date format is correct and data is stored as well but still getting error

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Hi guys i am working with laravel 5.7 while inserting data im getting issue of "Data Missing" but the data is inserting as well but still getting error here im sharing part of my code

**Model**

```
public function setApplicationDateAttribute($input)
{
    if($input != '') {
        $this->attributes['application_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('quickadmin.date_format'), $input)->format('Y-m-d');
    }else{
        $this->attributes['application_date'] = '';
    }
}
```

this is the funtion which is checking the date format for input data Now this is a file in my **config** folder named **quickadmin** i will show you the code of it

```
return [

/**
 * Datepicker configuration:
 */
'date_format'        => 'Y-m-d',
'date_format_jquery' => 'yy-mm-dd',
'time_format'        => 'H:i:s',
'time_format_jquery' => 'HH:mm:ss',

/**
 * Quickadmin settings
 */
'route'              => 'admin',
'homeRoute'          => 'admin',
'defaultRole'        => 1];
```

Now here is the code of **Controller**

```
$locumApplications = ModelName::create([
               'user_id' => $request->user_id,
               'locum_id' => $request->locum_id,
               'application_date' => $request->application_date
           ]);
```

it insert the data but give me error and if i remove the line `'application_date' => $request->application_date` it still show me the error

here i attached the error image
[image]

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968061/laravel-carbon-data-missing ?

Comment: @Iftikharuddin Bro i have checked many questions to sort out my error on stackoverflow even this link as well which you have provided still facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Your config: `config('quickadmin.date_format')` is `Y-m-d`

You are trying to set attributes

```
Carbon::createFromFormat(config('quickadmin.date_format'), $input)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Your `$input ($request->application_date)` must be on `Y-m-d` format

Should be work

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2019-03-14')->format('Y-m-d') //OP: 2019-03-14
```

Your date input and set attributes value look like the same format

Comment: @bhavijr i am providing the date in same format but still showing the same error

Comment: @YasirMehmood what is data type of `application_date` column?

Comment: @bhavijr data type is date

Answer (score 0):

Can you try overriding the default format in `YourModel` like below:

```
class YourModel extends Model {
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d'; // add your date format 
}
```