# Laravel Data missing

Tags: laravel, store, missing-data

I'm trying to save a form in my Laravel project and i'm getting errors.

My model

```
 protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'date_dentree',
        'date_mariage',


    ];

public function getDateDentreeAttribute($value)
{
    return $value ? Carbon::parse($value)->format(config('panel.date_format')) : null;

}

public function setDateDentreeAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date_dentree'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d') : null;

}

public function getDateMariageAttribute($value)
{
    return $value ? Carbon::parse($value)->format(config('panel.date_format')) : null;

}

public function setDateMariageAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date_mariage'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d') : null;

}
```

My Controller:

```
 public function store(StoreStagiaireRequest $request)
    {

        $stagiaire = Stagiaire::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('admin.home')->with('message', 'Informations enregistrées avec succés!');

    }
```

And last, in my config folder in the file panel.php  I have this:

```
<?php

return [
    'date_format'               => 'd-m-Y',
    'time_format'               => 'H:i:s',
    ],
    'registration_default_role' => '2',
];
```

What is the problem here?
I don't understand where the problem can come from?
Need a help!!!
Thanks.

Comment: Which error you get?

Comment: InvalidArgumentException
Data missing

Comment: I am not sure, but may be you need to set `protected $dateFormat` to `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` in your model

Comment: OK STA. Let me trying to do this. Thanks

Comment: This is not correct. Don't know if you mispasted, but this will throw error `return [
    'date_format'               => 'd-m-Y',
    'time_format'               => 'H:i:s',
    ],
    'registration_default_role' => '2',
];`

Comment: When I set:

 protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
It shows error:

    InvalidArgumentException Trailing data
And when I set:

 protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
It shows error:

    InvalidArgumentException Data missing
What kind of problem I have and how to resolve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435235/4575350

Comment: Thanks STA. It's the solution. May God bless You