# Problem with rawCreateFromFormat($format, $time, $tz) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, panel

I installed filament on my project for admin panel , I don't know why server will crash and stop , look at the photo that I attached , that is the error!!

It seems default code return empty array and this function will cause my project stop,  please help me how can I solve this problem ? thanks

```
public static function createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz = null)
    {
        $function = static::$createFromFormatFunction;

        if (!$function) {
            return static::rawCreateFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);
        }

        if (\is_string($function) && method_exists(static::class, $function)) {
            $function = [static::class, $function];
        }

        return $function(...\func_get_args());
    }
```

[first Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ILsH.png)

I just try to not send empty array with is_array() function but it wasn't correct at the result

it must be check if is empty array , then send correct parameter , check the below photo , that's the error , you can see [this is another error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPQnc.png)

I don't have any records in my database without blank columns in both created_at and updated_at columns , I can't find the solution please help me

this is the format of datetime fileds for related columns in my DB : 2023-09-25 21:23:03

Comment: Hi, please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968061/laravel-carbon-data-missing